# if fields empty or !empty run the query and dont display error for empty field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 3 different forms in 3 accordions but the query is one. `if (!empty($_POST)` this query, then submit the form. But it shows the error for the other forms that *online blah blah blah is error*. It shows this error for **empty fields**.

Is there a way to hide this error message for **empty** fields?

```
if(!empty($_POST)){

        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO 
            leave_req
            (
              `lvm_type`,
              `lvm_do`,
              `lvm_db`,
              `lvm_td`,
              `lvc_type`,
              `lvc_do`,
              `lvc_db`,
              `lvc_td`,
              `lvo_type`,
              `lvo_do`,
              `lvo_db`,
              `lvo_td`,
              `lvn_type`,
              `lvn_do`,
              `lvn_db`,
              `lvn_td`,
              `lv_reason`,
              `lv_usign`,
              `lv_rsign`,
              `lv_asign`,
              `lv_sec`,
              `lv_ip`,
              `lv_cdate`
            )
            values
            (
                '".addData($_POST['altype'])."',
                '".addData($_POST['aleave1'])."',
                '".addData($_POST['aleave2'])."',
                '".addData($_POST['altotal'])."',
                '".addData($_POST['cltype'])."',
                '".addData($_POST['cleave1'])."',
                '".addData($_POST['cleave2'])."',
                '".addData($_POST['cltotal'])."',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                'null',
                '".$ip."',
                now()
            )";
         echo "message submitted successfully";
         } else {
         echo "check your form"; }
```

Comment: you disable error reporting, put this line at the top `error_reporting(0)`

Comment: thanks alot for your kind response.. it is working fine now. thanks again

Comment: Is setting all those fields to null absolutely necessary? Or can you omit them in your PHP and set their default value from phpMyAdmin or similar?

Comment: well actually still its under construction. i mean i have to make 2 more forms yet i was checking that i have made 2 forms so if there is any error so i found this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice way of solving this problem is by using [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) combined with the ternary operator. Basically your ternary operator will evaluate to one of the given values, either the appropriate `$_POST` field or `null`. If there is a set `$_POST` field it will be made part of the query and if not `null` will be used instead.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO 
        leave_req
        (
          `lvm_type`,
          `lvm_do`,
          `lvm_db`,
          `lvm_td`,
          `lvc_type`,
          `lvc_do`,
          `lvc_db`,
          `lvc_td`,
          `lvo_type`,
          `lvo_do`,
          `lvo_db`,
          `lvo_td`,
          `lvn_type`,
          `lvn_do`,
          `lvn_db`,
          `lvn_td`,
          `lv_reason`,
          `lv_usign`,
          `lv_rsign`,
          `lv_asign`,
          `lv_sec`,
          `lv_ip`,
          `lv_cdate`
        )
        values
        (
            '" . (isset($_POST['altype']) ? addData($_POST['altype']) : 'null') . "',
            '" . (isset($_POST['aleave1']) ? addData($_POST['aleave1']) : 'null') . "',
            '" . (isset($_POST['aleave2']) ? addData($_POST['aleave2']) : 'null') . "',
            '" . (isset($_POST['altotal']) ? addData($_POST['altotal']) : 'null') . "',
            '" . (isset($_POST['cltype']) ? addData($_POST['cltype']) : 'null') . "',
            '" . (isset($_POST['cleave1']) ? addData($_POST['cleave1']) : 'null') . "',
            '" . (isset($_POST['cleave2']) ? addData($_POST['cleave2']) : 'null') . "',
            '" . (isset($_POST['cltotal']) ? addData($_POST['cltotal']) : 'null') . "',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            'null',
            '".$ip."',
            now()
        )";
        echo "message submitted successfully";
 } else {
    echo "check your form"; }
 ?>
```

Comment: well thanks for your response. i tried this but its giving error on )"; before echo "message submitted successfully"; it says unexpected ; would you please assist what is the problem ???

Comment: My fault, I used dots instead of columns in ternary operators. Corrected all the errors in my post.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (isset($_POST['form1']) or
    isset($_POST['form2']) or
    isset($_POST['form3']) )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: please describe little more to understand you. how it doesnt work ? some error message ? it passes to else statment ?

Comment: it does not show any error message. and even not submitting the form by using this. please tell me if it can be solved

Comment: have you changed the names form1 and form2 and form3 ?

Comment: actually the full code is too long i cant post the rest query is same i put only put for 2 forms i removed the 3rd form.. using 2 forms right now...
if (isset($_POST['alform']) or
    isset($_POST['clform']) {

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36437/discussion-between-usman610-and-echo-me)

Comment: why chat and you already accepted above answer as solved your issue. ?

Comment: yes issue is solved. just to have a diffetent and another solution for that issue. its ok my problem is solved. thanks alot